# How to update the child nuget package in dot net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, nuget

During pen testing of web application using the NetSparker Tool.
The *<kbd>System.Text.RegularExpressions</kbd>* of version of 4.3.0 was having security vulnerability.
The solution is to update the nuget package to  4.3.1 version.

The project is indirectly dependent on the *<kbd>System.Text.RegularExpressions</kbd>* package. That the project is using the *<kbd>Microsoft.Data.SqlClient</kbd>* of version 2.1.0. Even if I upgrade this to 2.1.3, this package is not upgrading its child package <kbd>System.Text.RegularExpressions</kbd> to 4.3.1. By default the acceptable nuget package version of *<kbd>System.Text.RegularExpressions</kbd>* for *<kbd>Microsoft.Data.SqlClient</kbd>* is >=4.3.0.

Need help on how to upgrade only the child nuget package
*System.Text.RegularExpressions* to version 4.3.1
[image]

Comment: Explicitly include a `System.Text.RegularExpression` package reference yourself? A direct reference to version 4.3.1+ should also force the rest to resolve to that version. (A better reference might be `(4.3.0,)`, which allows anything higher but specifically excludes 4.3.0, per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/concepts/package-versioning).)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Tried this earlier, but it will add it as the direct reference to the project. any solution to update only as the child package just like we do it in npm ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what would be *wrong* with having a direct reference to it in the project itself. The only way that would be worse is if somehow, not a single other package ended up referencing it and it is thus superfluous as a direct reference, but that's not really going to happen with `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. NuGet packages are far less fine-grained than npm packages. You're not going to be the one updating all those MS packages to use a newer version, in any case -- only MS can do that (in such a way that things stick).

Comment: What's wrong with having a direct reference to it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in it. I just want to know if there is anyway other than adding a direct reference.

Comment: Is this one of those false positive vulnerability triggers for dotnet? What version of dotnet are your using? Please have a look at https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1786#issuecomment-755619934

Comment: Its not false positive. We were uising dot Net core 3.0. Untimely I had resolved to issue by directly adding the reference on the parent project and rest of the project started to refer the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I had too many references in the child project. I did a direct reference in the parent project, System.Text.RegularExpressions & Microsoft.Data.SqlClient pointing to the secure version of the nuget package.

After, this all the child project which was referencing insecure version of System.Text.RegularExpressions & Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, started to take the  version mentioned on the parent project.

Comment: how you did that need more explanation